# How to return a toast to anything typed on EditText but a specific word?

Tags: android, android-edittext, toast

I am currently developing my first android application, which is actually my first contact with java ever. Therefore, I suppose this question has an obvious answer to experienced developers, but I couldn't find anything at SO or anywhere else. 
The following EditText has two toasts (I'm not sure if that sounded right). One is shown if the user types a specific word (in this case, `Please` is shown if the user types `Magic word` and presses the button). I would like the another toast to appear if the user types anything else but that word (anything but "Magic word") when clicking the button.

```
EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
{

if(editText1.getText().toString().trim().equals("Magic word"))
{
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
        "Please", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}                                                                                                                                        
} 
else if (editText1.getText().toString().trim().equals())
{
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
    "You didn't say the magic word", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
}
});
```

I apologize for my poor english. Hopefully, I made myself understood.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Remove the second `if` clause and leave only `...} else {...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code give you the solution:

```
final EditText editText1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);        
    Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final String edittext=editText1.getText().toString();
            if(edittext.trim().equals("Magic word"))
            {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Please", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }  

            else
            {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "You didn't say the magic word", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

More simple way!!

```
String hello = editText1.getText().toString();
```

and then,

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The text is" +hello , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

More accurately "Magic word" isn't a word, its two with a space. The first if statement will require the text in the EditText to be exactly that for the statement to be true. If you actually intended for "magic word" to merely be somewhere in the text typed into the EditText to show a Toast that says please, look into using String.contains() or regex for the first comparison.

For all other conditions there's no need to check the value of the EditText. In other words remove the second if just keep else as Luksprog mentioned.